# How do I exclude a filename that contains a specific text when using the Data Transfer feature on BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, transfer, data-transfer

I'm using Google Cloud Storage as a source and BigQuery as the destination for a Data Transfer feature that's available in BigQuery.So, on the data source details when creating a new data transfer I need to input the 'Cloud Storage URI', but I don't know how to exclude files with a certain text such as '_All_Data' on the file name.

I've tried to use the pattern bucket/filepath1/2023/*/*/filename_2023*!_All_Data.csv which was provided by ChatGPT, but it didn't work. I was expecting that I would be able to extract all the files in 2023 with the filename starting with 'filename_2023', and exclude all the files that contains '_All_Data'.

Basically, my expectations is that I would be able to extract files such as:

- bucket/filepath1/2023/05/01/filename_20230501.csv
- bucket/filepath1/2023/05/03/filename_20230503.csv
- bucket/filepath1/2023/03/04/filename_20230304.csv

And exclude files such as:

- bucket/filepath1/2023/05/01/filename_20230501_All_Data.csv
- bucket/filepath1/2023/05/03/filename_20230503_All_Data.csv
- bucket/filepath1/2023/03/04/filename_20230304_All_Data.csv